# Setting up municipalities run by Jews in Eretz Yisrael

Tags: eretz-yisrael, politics-government, state-of-israel, cities, zionism

Even those who are against the **State** of Israel have no problem with living in the **Land** of Israel. Is there anything (in Torah, Halacha) that would prevent a group of Jews from coming to Eretz Yisrael and establishing a government to provide services for the people living in the Land?

I'm essentially asking what's the problem with today's state if all it does is provide government services like other countries, protect the people that live there, etc. Does it matter that they are Jewish?

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Oaths

Comment: @YK Why see there if none of those seem to apply to this case (even if they are binding)?

Comment: I was under the impression that Munkatczers were opposed to living in E"Y after the advent of Zionism. Something about Zionism having polluted the kedushah of the Land.